# Prolog - converting a list into a list of terms

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog and sometimes can't wrap my head around certain things. I know how to convert a list into terms in this format:

```
listOfTerms(ListOfArgs,Name, ListOfResults)
listOfTerms([[1,2],[100,99],[5,11]],+,T).
T = +([1, 2], [100, 99], [5, 11]).
```

How do I make it look like this?

```
T = [1+2, 100+99, 5+11].

listOfTerms(Lst,F,[1+2, 100+99, 5+11]).
Lst = [[1, 2], [100, 99], [5, 11]],
F = + .
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your first example does not have T used anywhere, yet it appears in the result.

Comment: Sorry about that. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
listOfTerms(ListOfArgs, Name, ListOfResults):-
    maplist(map(Name), ListOfArgs, ListOfResults).

map(Functor, Arg, Term):-
  Term=..[Functor|Arg].
```

Use `=.. (univ)` predicate to build the terms from their arguments or to get the arguments from the term, and use `maplist` to apply this transformation to each pair of elements from the list.

If you want to avoid using `maplist`, you can just define a recursive procedure:

```
listOfTerms([], _, []).
listOfTerms([Arg|ListOfArgs], Functor, [Term|ListOfTerms]):-
  Term=..[Functor|Arg],
  listOfTerms(ListOfArgs, Functor, ListOfTerms).
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to do this recursively and without maplist?

Comment: @user1834372: of course, see edited answer. All you would need is to apply univ predicate over the elements of both lists.